# Using or inside an if statement - unexpected or wrong results

Tags: apex

Hi I am having some issues with some simple conditions on an if statement when using 'or' to define the action, the 
below is an example that will have as a result a string with eleven characters, however for some reason the 
else if statement keep been excecute  when that is not correct

Doesnt have apex the functionality of using this 'or' inside and if statement? however when using the code below on 
the developer console I dont get any error and it is been exccecuted. So I dont understand what is going on

```
string a = 'test string';
integer b;
b = a.length();
if(b <= 2){
    system.debug('b is less or equal to 2');
}else if(b > 2 || b<5){
    system.debug(b + ' is in between 2 and 5');
}else{
    system.debug('definetly longer than 5');
}
```

the result:
[image: Using or within if statement, APEX]

Thanks

Comment: you're using an OR.  11>2.  check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(b > 2 || b < 5)` is true for the number 11 (11 is greater than 2).

Perhaps you meant instead `(b > 2 && b < 5)`, which will be true for numbers between 2 and 5 (exclusive)?